# What can I do with mold under grouting?

Tags: shower, mold

In my new place, there's a semi-transparent grouting/glaze over the corners of my shower - and there's mold growing beneath them?

Is this normal? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem and here's what I did.

- using a scraping tool I removed the old grouting-glaze
- I used [Zep](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001SQSF3O) (incredibly effective with mold but really stinky)
- then I cleaned the shower with water and let dry
- purchased a tube of silicone caulk from Home depot
- applied the a new layer of caulk where the old one was removed

To maintain a mold/mildew free shower I use [Arm & Hammer Clean Shower](http://www.buy.com/prod/arm-hammer-daily-shower-cleaner-fresh-clean-32-oz/q/sellerid/28612218/loc/66357/204600330.html) every day after I take a shower. I spray the stuff around the shower cabin right after I get out of the shower. It has a nice scent and it does a really good job keeping mold and mildew out!

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to get around re-caulking to fix this.  Just realize that mold can be growing within the walls (particularly on drywall that isn't mold resistant).  This means you may want to consider switching to an opaque caulk and accept that this will be a reoccurring process.

Comment: There are caulks available that are mold/mildew resistant.